# Why does boolean indexing reverse the order of axis?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((5,4,3,2))
i = np.array([[True, False], [False, False], [False, True]])
print(x[4,:,i].shape) # (2, 4)
```

Why is `x[4,:,i].shape` (2, 4) instead of (4, 2)?

The indexing array with the 2 `True` values is after `:` which corresponding to the axis with 4 values. (4, 2) seems to make more sense.

Comment: It's the slice in the middle.  This a mixed basic and advanced indexing; It's documented and .also  discussed in numerous SO.

Comment: I explored way this happens in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76893624/shapes-of-arrays-obtained-by-mixed-basic-and-advanced-indexing-in-numpy-ndarray

Comment: @hpaulj I know the behavior of mixed indexing. What I did not expect is that `4` here is treated as advanced indexing. When I change it to `4:5`, everything runs as expected.

Comment: Right a scalar normally is basic, removing that dimension.  But for this kind of mixed indexing it counts as advanced.  In fact this is the most common case..Devs know about it, but find it impossible to correct. My first linked answer suggests part of the 'why'. .