# Numpy Indexing Flips Dimensions

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array `a` of shape `(8193, 10, 15, 2, 2)`. Now, i want to select 2 elements along the 2nd and one along the 5th dimension, starting to count dimensions at 1. However, the slice operations seems to rotate the dimension somehow, and `a[:,[0,3],:,:,0].shape` results in `(2, 8193, 15, 2)`, i.e. one of the later dimensions ends up being the first (?!). Consecutive indexing `a[:,[0,3]][:,:,:,:,0].shape` yields `(8193, 2, 15, 2)`, i.e. the expected result. Also `a[:,[0,3],0,:,:].shape` yields `(8193, 2, 2, 2)`, thus, works as expected. Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: This mixed advanced and basic indexing comes up periodically on SO, e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76893624/shapes-of-arrays-obtained-by-mixed-basic-and-advanced-indexing-in-numpy-ndarray

Comment: Yay, I kind of expected this, however, I didn't find anything searching for the keywords from my title. Maybe my post will serve as a gateway for people googling for the same keywords, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this NumPy issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/25653), this is expected behaviour.

To quote the response to the filed issue:

> This is working as documented. Quoting from https://numpy.org/doc/1.21/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing:
>
> > Two cases of index combination need to be distinguished:
> >
> > - The advanced indexes are separated by a slice, Ellipsis or newaxis. For example x[arr1, :, arr2].
> > - The advanced indexes are all next to each other. For example x[..., arr1, arr2, :] but not x[arr1, :, 1] since 1 is an advanced index in this regard.
> >
> > In the first case, the dimensions resulting from the advanced indexing operation come first in the result array, and the subspace dimensions after that. In the second case, the dimensions from the advanced indexing operations are inserted into the result array at the same spot as they were in the initial array (the latter logic is what makes simple advanced indexing behave just like slicing).

Your situation appears to be the first. In which case the dimensions resulting from the slice come first, then the other dimensions.

Comment: Note: I'm still puzzled as to why `a[:, [0,1,3], :, :, [0,1]]` results in an IndexError with a shape mismatch. And the case `a = np.ones((8193, 10, 15, 2, 5)) ; a[:, [0,1,3], :, :, [0,1,2]].shape` equals `(3, 8193, 15, 2)`, so the second and last dimensions appear to get merged.

Comment: In case of `a[:, [0,1,3], :, :, [0,1]]`, we need to make the index arrays _broadcastable_ with each other. E.g. `a[:, [[0],[1],[3]], :, :, [0,1]].shape`. The same in the second case, to obtain a Cartesian product of indexes, separate them on different dimensions, like `a[:, [[0],[1],[3]], :, :, [0,1,2]]`